# Insert_batch CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert some values coming from a form as array using the function insert_batch with CodeIgniter.

This the code in the **controller**:

```
$data_product = array(
'quantity'=> $quantity,
'price'=> $price,
'productID'=> $product_id
);

$this->load->model('product_ordered');
$this->product_ordered->insert_quantity_products($data_product);
```

This is the code in the **model insert_quantity_products**

```
public function insert_quantity_products($data){
$this->db->insert_batch('orders', $data);
}
```

And this is the database error

```
Unknown column '0' in 'field list'
INSERT INTO `orders` (`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES ('3','1','1'),
('358.00','458.00','324.00'), ('1','39','69')
```

The unknown columns should be quantity, price and productID

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: insert_batch function use 2D array but you used 1D array.

Answer (score 2):

in controller

```
$this->load->model('product_ordered');
$this->product_ordered->insert_quantity_products();
```

in model

1. if you are using single input use this(`$this->db->insert`)

   `public function insert_quantity_products()
   {
   $data_product = array(
   'quantity'=> $quantity,
   'price'=> $price,
   'productID'=> $product_id
   );

   $this->db->insert('orders', $data_product);
   }`

// Produces: `INSERT INTO orders (quantity, price, productID) VALUES ('$quantity', '$price', '$product_id')`

2. if you are yousing batch insert use this (`$this->db->insert_batch`)

   `public function insert_quantity_products()
   {
       $data_product = array(
           array(
           'quantity'=> $quantity,
           'price'=> $price,
           'productID'=> $product_id
           );
           array(
           'quantity'=> $quantity2,
           'price'=> $price2,
           'productID'=> $product_id2
           );
       );
   $this->db->insert_batch('orders', $data_product);
   }`

// Produces: `INSERT INTO orders (quantity, price, productID) VALUES ('$quantity', '$price', '$product_id'),('$quantity2', '$price2', '$product_id2')`

Answer (score 0):

Your try to use function `insert_batch`.

So check documentation:

The first parameter will contain the table name, the second is an associative array of values.

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);
```

This is example how you must set your data.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. The column are not recognized Unknown column '0' in 'field lis

Comment: in your case when you insert only one row, you may try use `insert` instead `insert_batch` and set your data as before in 1D array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a 2 Dimensional array for the $data_product.
This means you controller change $data_product as below:

`$data_product[] = array('quantity'=> $quantity, 'price'=> $price, 'productID'=> $product_id);`