# CI: Master Detail for User Registration Form doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, master-detail

I want to create a user registration form where I allow user to be able to put as many emails and phones as they want just like Google Contacts.

I already created the form that allow user to add or remove the input field for emails and phones dynamically. here's the image of it:
[User Registration Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUEvL.png)

this is the model script I use..

```
public function store_email() {
        if (! $this->validate_email()) return FALSE;
        $this->db->trans_begin();
        try {
            $this->db->insert($this->table_user, $this);
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            foreach ($this->email as $key => $value) $this->email[$key]['user_id'] = $id;
            $this->db->insert_batch($this->table_email, $this->email);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
public function store_phone() {
        if (! $this->validate_phone()) return FALSE;
        $this->db->trans_begin();
        try {
            $this->db->insert($this->table_user, $this);
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            foreach ($this->phone as $key => $value) $this->phone[$key]['user_id'] = $id;
            $this->db->insert_batch($this->table_phone, $this->phone);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

this is the controller script I use..

```
public function store() {

        $this->model->first_name = $this->input->post('first_name', TRUE);
        $this->model->middle_name = $this->input->post('middle_name', TRUE);
        $this->model->last_name = $this->input->post('last_name', TRUE);
        $this->model->email = [];
        $this->model->phone = [];

        foreach ($this->input->post('label_id', TRUE) as $key => $value) $this->model->email[$key]['label_id'] = $value;
        foreach ($this->input->post('email', TRUE) as $key => $value) $this->model->email[$key]['email'] = $value;
        foreach ($this->input->post('label_id', TRUE) as $key => $value) $this->model->phone[$key]['label_id'] = $value;
        foreach ($this->input->post('phone', TRUE) as $key => $value) $this->model->phone[$key]['phone'] = $value;

        if ($this->model->store_email() === TRUE) {
            if ($this->model->store_phone() === TRUE) {
                $notification = 'Register success! You may login now!';
            } else {
                $notification = 'Register fail!';
            }
        } else {
            $notification = 'Register fail!';
        }

        $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('Success',$notification);
        redirect(base_url().'login');

    }
```

I run this code and it gives me error saying Array to String conversion and I am not able to store any data into database.
any help would be really appreciated.

Updated:

here's the error I get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1496

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-master-detail-trans\application\models\Customer_model.php
Line: 103
Function: insert_batch

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-master-detail-trans\application\controllers\Customer.php
Line: 50
Function: store

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-master-detail-trans\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

the table I use for this:

- Table_User (id, name, username, password)
- Table_Email (id, email, user_id, label_id)
- Table_Phone (id, phone, user_id, label_id)
- Table_Label (id, label)

Comment: are you using stored procedure.?

Comment: i'm not. I use insert_batch to store the emails and phones into Table Emails and Table Phones based on data user put in the form. when I only store the emails, it's working. but when I try to store the phones as well.. it gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

For Array to string conversion Error you can use IMplode Function as below:

```
 $string_version = implode(',', $original_array)
```

Please Edit your post and put whole error so that we can help you out.

Comment: Use that implode where you have the error and see the result. If not work then post the error here. Feel free to upvote my answer if your issue solved.
Thanks

Comment: I have post the error. I try to use insert_batch to insert data of emails and phones into table email and table phone based on new user data.

Comment: when I only store the data of emails using insert_batch, it's working. but when I store the data of emails and phones using insert_batch in the functions I created, it won't work.

Comment: See this for referral
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466909/insert-batch-codeigniter?rq=1

try to print the array of $this->phone and email so that you can see multiple arrays are coming or not and then use insert_batch

Comment: this one doesn't actually answer my question because emails and phones are stored in different Tables.

Answer (score 0):

add this line just before batch_insert code

```
 $phone_details = implode(',',$this->phone);
```

Then make changes in batch insert like below

```
 $this->db->insert_batch($this->table_phone, $phone_details); // phone number will be stored in , separated format i.e. 1234567890,3216549870
```

Comment: so should I put them all into one public function store() in model?

Comment: that's best practice. for now make those changes and see if it solves.

Comment: and what about the foreach part? I am really sorry but this is confusing me.. as when I only use the public function store() which is for storing emails it works but when I call public function store2() which is for storing phones in the controller as well both of the functions don't work

Comment: In your store function you are calling store phone number too. here $this->model->store_phone(). so no need to call another function for storing phone.

Comment: best thing is put your table structure that helps a lot

Comment: but $this->model->store_phone() is in controller. I use this to call the public function store_phone() from the model. if I don't use this.. and just use $this->model->store_email() I able to get the data of email to get stored and the codes work. but when I use store_phone(), both functions don't work

Comment: add table structure to question. that gives clear picture

Comment: I put the table structure to my question could you please check see it?

Comment: to store phone r u calling separate function. no right?

Comment: yes I can different function from model called store_phone()

Comment: do you happen to know how to merge two functions, store_email() and store_phone() into one? the error probably because in controller, I call store_email() first then store_phone() which cause the error

Comment: $this->db->insert_batch($this->table_phone, $this->phone); this line has error. proper syntax is $this->db->insert_batch(tablename,dataarray);

Comment: but $this->db->insert_batch($this->table_email, $this->email); for storing the emails work tho. so I don't get why $this->db->insert_batch($this->table_phone, $this->phone); doesn't work..